# Validate floating point numbers in datagridview textbox column

Tags: c#, winforms, number-formatting, datagridviewcolumn

I'm working with Winforms and C#.

I have a datagridview I'm using for a cricket project.  I need a column that will only accept numbers and a decimal value of 0 to 5.

EG:

> 10.0 (ok)
>   10.1 (ok)
>   10.2 (ok)
>   10.3 (ok)
>   10.4 (ok)
>   10.5 (ok)
>   10.6 (NOT OK) etc

I can set the cell format to `N1` but that doesn't restrict the floating point part to just 0 to 5.

Does anyone have a nice solution for what I'm trying to achieve?

P.S - Sorry about the lack of code, but I'm typing this up quickly during my lunch break at work.

Comment: This doesn't sound like a matter of formatting - this sounds like a matter of validation.

Comment: Yeah, I suppose it is.  Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

This is validation, not formatting. Use a  regular expression (C# Regex class) to check the input.

If you want the output as above, create a function which returns a string and the value as a parameter. Use that function in the gridview (e.g. text property of a label) and match against the regex ^\d*.[0-5]$

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  I'll give it a try when I get a chance in the next day or two.  Cheers for taking the time.